# Copy sheet to new workbook as values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the **final input** sheet of **data** workbook to a new workbook as only values

I've tried this but it pastes the data as values

```
Sub CopyToNew()
Sheets("Final Input").Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim newWb As Workbook
    Dim newWbPath As String: newWbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NewWB.xlsx"
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FinalCountDown").Cells.Copy
    newWb.Worksheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    newWb.SaveAs newWbPath
    newWb.Close

End Sub
```

- It copies the cells from `ThisWorkbook("FinalCountDown")` to the first worksheet of a new Workbook.
- Then the new workbook is named "NewWB.xlsx" and is saved in the same file as ThisWorkbook through the variable `newWbPath`.
- At the end the `newWb` is closed with `newWb.Close`.

Comment: Is it possible to add something that will paste the data as values to the above code that I mentioned?